# dbt relationship test compilation error: test definition dictionary must have exactly one key

Tags: dbt

I'm a new user of dbt, trying to write a relationship test:

```yaml
- name: PROTOCOL_ID
  tests:
    - relationships:
    to: ref('Animal_Protocols')
    field: id
```

I am getting this error:

```
Compilation Error
Invalid test config given in models/Animal_Protocols/schema.yml:
test definition dictionary must have exactly one key, got [('relationships', None), ('to', "ref('Animal_Protocols')"), ('field', 'id')] instead (3 keys)
@: UnparsedNodeUpdate(original_file_path='model...ne)
```

"unique" and "not-null" tests in the same file are working fine, but I have a similar error with "accepted_values".

I am using dbt cli version 0.21.0 with Snowflake on MacOS Big Sur 11.6.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are very close! I'm 96% sure that this is an indentation issue -- the #1 pain point of working with YAML. The solution is that both `to` and `field` need to be indented below the `relationships` key as opposed to at the same level.

See the [Tests dbt docs page](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/tests/#generic-tests) for an example

```yaml
  - name: PROTOCOL_ID
    tests:
      - relationships:
          to: ref('Animal_Protocols')
          field: id
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was a good clue, though it wasn't the exact problem.

My original post didn't show the indentation that I had.  My editor was setup for 2 spaces of indentation at each level.  That works for most levels (e.g. "-tests:") but not for the level immediately below "-relationships:". It worked once I changed the "to:" and "from:" from 2 to 4 spaces of indentation.

Arrrrrgggggghhhhhh!  I always knew that YAML's syntax is a bad idea.

Comment: ...smacks head on desk, yup all the way

Comment: Ah thanks for your answer, I had a different problem (dbt expectations) but the answer was the same :)

Comment: My dear god, I was looking for this issue for a while, I changed from 2 to 4 spaces and it got solved. Thank you so much for adding this comment